# Prevent R and devtools from downloading tar / tgz packages already installed outside of R

Tags: r, rstudio, homebrew, devtools, install.packages

I just installed R ([`RStudio`](https://www.rstudio.com/)) on a new Mac computer (Big Sur) and have been installing the usual packages I need.

Upon installing `devtools` with `install.packages("devtools")`, I see that R/RStudio is downloading `brew`, which I assume is [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh/).

However, I had previously installed [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh/) on my computer, outside of `R`, and have been using it to install packages like [`tesseract`](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/).

My questions are

1. did `install.packages()` and/or `devtools` have installed a duplicate of Brew on my computer (i.e. is my post legitimate) , or the two Brews are unrelated?
2. Is there a way to tell R/RStudio to look at a certain path/folder in my computer before downloading duplicate apps in its own folder?
3. If answer to 1 is no, are there instances where crosstalk happens, as I assume is the case for Tesseract (or Tesseract and the R package of the same name do not communicate at all)

Motivation: I want to avoid cluttering my flash drive with unused or duplicate packages, and avoid complex cleanups.

I am thinking of something like `echo "export PATH= (...) $PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`.

Of note, R displayed `"First use of Tesseract: copying language data..."` and I wonder if it downloaded the additional languages package that I chose not to download with Homebrew. (I was hoping to find a way to install only 2-3 additional languages with Homebrew, not all of them).

Comment: devtools has a dependency on the R package [brew](https://cran.r-project.org/package=brew) which is a "Templating Framework for Report Generation". It doesn't seem to have anything to do with homebrew. I think you just misinterpreted the messages you were seeing.

Comment: `install.packages` is installing R packages, not the kind packages managed by Homebrew.

Comment: Thank you, I revised my question to account for this possibility and go beyond (to invite an exhaustive and acceptable answer).